# Generating Likert-type response: A follow-up

Tags: r, categorical-data, simulation, count-data, likert

I want to follow up on [this great answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/374500/124093). The answer explains in an intuitive way how to generate Likert-type responses for any number of items from `N` participants on a single latent construct and then provides some `R` code.

To better understand that process, I want to limit my questions to generating only one Likert-type item (i.e., `item1`).  **Disclaimer:** I have some basic, fundamental knowledge of stats but love to learn things in plain language.

**(1)** Why (*statistically or software/simulation-wise*) the continuous `latent` construct is to be standard normal distributed (specifically why its `mean_latent=` is set to `0`)?

**(2)** In [this great answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/374500/124093), cutpoints of `c(-Inf,-2.5,-1, 1,2.5,Inf)` are referred to as *"fairly unbiased"*. Why kind of bias (*systematic bias, cutting bias*) is meant here and with respect to what?

**(3)** Closely related to **(2)**, noise resulting from the imprecision in `item1` compared to `latent` is regulated using  `item1_sd`. This makes the resulting `item1_likert` to be more or less correlated with `latent`. But doesn't less correlation denote more bias (systematically `item1_likert` misrepresenting `latent` regardless of how large `N` is)?

```
likert <- function(N_participant=1e4, mean_latent =0, item1_sd = .00001, 
         cutpoints = c(-2.5, -1,1, 2.5) ){

N      = N_participant        # this is how much data I'll generate
latent = rnorm(N,mean = mean_latent)  # this is the actual latent variable I want to be measuring

graphics.off()
org.par <- par(no.readonly = TRUE)
on.exit(par(org.par))
par(mfrow=c(3,1),mgp = c(1.5, 0.14, 0), mar = c(2.5, 2.6, 1.8, .5), 
    tck = -0.02)

hist(latent,main = NA)

item1_continous = latent + rnorm(N, mean=0, sd=item1_sd)

hist(item1_continous,main = NA)

item1_likert = findInterval(item1_continous, vec= c(-Inf,cutpoints,Inf))

plot(table(item1_likert),main = NA,frame = FALSE,ylab="Frequency")

cor(item1_likert, latent)
}
##--- EXAMPLES OF USE:

likert(cutpoints = c(-2.5,-1, 1,2.5))
likert(cutpoints = 0:4)
```